# how to join 4 .json files in the same file and then export it as a single .json file?

Tags: python, json, concatenation

I am using the following code to concatenate 4 json files:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

Nomi1 = pd.read_json("Nomina1.json")["data"]
Nomi2 = pd.read_json("Nomina2.json")["data"]
Nomi3 = pd.read_json("Nomina3.json")["data"]
Nomi4 = pd.read_json("Nomina4.json")["data"]
combi = pd.concat([Nomi1,Nomi2,Nomi3,Nomi4])
```

when doing a "print" it is effectively concatenating the 4 files, but it is generating the following error when I want to export these files as a single .json:

```
combi.to_json('Nomina MCO.json')
```

Message Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-d8767edeee51> in <module>
      6 Nomi4 = pd.read_json("Nomina4.json")["data"]
      7 combi = pd.concat([Nomi1,Nomi2,Nomi3,Nomi4])
----> 8 combi.to_json('Nomina MCO.json')

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in _format_axes(self)
    203     def _format_axes(self):
    204         if not self.obj.index.is_unique and self.orient == "index":
--> 205             raise ValueError(f"Series index must be unique for orient='{self.orient}'")
    206 
    207 

ValueError: Series index must be unique for orient='index'
```

When I do the same and export it as a .csv it works perfectly, do you know why it won't let me create it as a single .json?

I need to concatenate these 4 .json files, and then export them in a file called "combined.json"

Comment: You have multiple rows with the same index value which would result in creating an object with multiple copies of the same key. You need to reset the index using `reset_index` to fix that, or perhaps use `orient='records'`

Comment: Thanks! I use this line and now working

combi.reset_index(inplace=True)

Comment: Good to hear. I'm glad that helped.